# Too many WCF channels

Tags: c#, wcf

In our system there are multiple "sites" communicating with one another via WCF. Each site exposes ~20 interfaces over NetTCP binding.

When a site consumes the interfaces of the peer site, it will open a separate TCP socket for each channel. This means that if I want to regularly use all the interfaces, ~20 TCP sockets will remain open for each peer site.

The number of peers each site has is currently relatively small (10-15), but this will have to grow to ~100 in the near future. My concern is that this will require each site to have ~2000 incoming sockets which seems excessive. I can't put my finger on a specific problem, but it just feels wrong. For example, this greatly exceeds WCF's default MaxConcurrentConnections (default value is 10).

Is this a good design for the system? Should I be looking at consolidating all those interfaces into a single interface (and thus a single channel)? Will I be able to send messages concurrently on a single channel (I think not)? Perhaps I should consider a message queue system?

Any comments or ideas would be welcome.

Comment: @Fabske It appears to be obsolete as of .NET 4.5 :( See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netpeertcpbinding.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling PortSharing? i.e http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734772.aspx

Comment: Maybe I'm reading it wrong, but I think it won't help me here. My concern is that a single client will have to open 20 different sockets in order to consume all the services. Won't that be the case even with PortSharing? The client will still have to call e.g. `ChannelFactory.CreateChannel` for each interface.